# Android exception.getMessage() kills App

Tags: android, exception

I have a question. Let's say I have the following code:

```
try{
    //do something that could throw an exception
}
catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println(e.getMessage();
}
```

Executing this in the emulator works fine, but when I tried to run it on my phone, the app craches (NullPointerException, apparently "e" is null).

How can that be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope. If exception occurs than `e` must have something inside (and thats the purpose).

Comment: Well, that's what I thought as well. However it seems that now the problem isn't occuring again, for some reason...

Answer (score 0):

If you use System.out to print your logs, you should be able to see the error in LogCat under the `System.out` tag. Try checking that out and come back again.